# MYSQL How to add virtual column into existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this `'data'` table below with columns `'INITIAL','BETWIXT','ENDING'` with values inserted;

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

CREATE TABLE data (
    INITIAL INT NOT NULL,
    BETWIXT INT NOT NULL,
    ENDING VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT 
    INTO data(data.INITIAL,data.BETWIXT,data.ENDING) 
    VALUES
    (30,40,"N0"), 
    (60,80,"N1"), 
    (90,120,"N2"),
    (120,160,"N3"),
    (150,200,"N4"); 

SELECT DISTINCT ENDING AS "HI"
    FROM data
    WHERE data.INITIAL BETWEEN 60 AND 150;
```

But I'm approaching to insert the "HI" virtual column into the main table 'data' so it can be visualize as

```
INITIAL  BETWIXT  ENDING  HI 

30       40      N0     N1

60       80      N1     N2

90       120     N2     N3

120      160     N3     N4
 
150      200     N4
```

Instead of just single virtual column, how do I write a code in order to construct the above?.

Comment: It's helpful to know the mysql version you are working on. And the onus is on you to tell us the logic as is I would GUESS you need LEAD (if you have version 8 or above) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your output example is not correct coz for the 1st row you should get a null value, not 'N1'. Regarding your question, just list all columns in your query:

```
select t.initial,
t.betwixt,
t.ending,
case when t.initial between 60 and 150 then t.ending else NULL end as 'HI'
from data t;
```

If you really need the output with a gap of 1 step, then see the code from @Pankaj post

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get next value of ending column in HI column.
If so, LEAD can be used.

```
select initial,BETWIXT,ending,lead(ending) over (order by initial) hi from data;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=557095440968dcc5ce2dfc83d981ec23).